# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) .whats wrong?

Tags: php

include('Connect.php')
$sql = "insert into medicaments values ('$_REQUEST[code_med]','$_REQUEST[name_med]',                                    '$_REQUEST[exp_date]','$_REQUEST[qte_med] ')";

mysqli_query( $sql , $con);
echo " Record Inserted Successfully = " . mysqli_affected_rows($con);
mysqli_close($con)

Comment: put semicolon after include statement;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after `include('Connect.php')` add ; like this `include('Connect.php');`